# iOS kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange not all bluetooth devices detected

Tags: ios, bluetooth, voip

I am using kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange delegate to detect whether bluetooth or a headset are connected to the phone for a VoIP app.  The actual bluetooth devices can be obtained from:

```
AVAudioSessionRouteDescription *route = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute];



for(AVAudioSessionPortDescription *port in route.outputs) {
    NSLog(@"AUDIO_OUTPUT IS NOW: %@",port.portType);
}
```

HOWEVER, not all bluetooth devices are being detected in this method.  This is not detected when paired with car bluetooth hosts that exchange vcard information, etc, like Audi.  In fact, if you check the currentRoute even when paired, it doesn't show up as valid route.  So what is different about car bluetooth devices vs headsets and how do I detect ALL bluetooth speaker/mics to be used for a phone call?  The default iOS phone app has no problem listing each device.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. But I am interested if you still have that problem and if you were able to solve it?